# Retrieving images in nestJS

Tags: image, file-upload, nestjs, profile

```
@Controller('UploadMedia')
//@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard) 
export class creativeLibraryController {
    constructor(private readonly creativeLibraryService : creativeLibraryService){}
//':id/campaignId/creativeId'
    @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination:'./file1',
        filename: editFileName
      }),

    }))
    //@Param('id') id:number,@Param(' creativeId') creativeId:number,@Param('campaignId') campaignId:number,
    async uploadFile( @UploadedFile() file,@Request() req: Observable<object>) {
      
      const response = {
       // originalname: file.originalname,
        filename: file.filename,
        //filepath:file.path,
        
      };

      return response;
    }
```

I use the above code to upload an image using nest JS

```
@Get('image/:filename')
seeUploadedFile(@Param('filename') image, @Res() res) { 
  return res.sendFile(image, { root: './file1' });
}
```

I can retrieve my file by the above code too.... Can anyone suggest modifications I have to do in order to upload a specific content? As an example a profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but I think a ParseFilePipe might be what you need to make sure only certain file types make it through.

```html
@UploadedFile(
  new ParseFilePipe({
    validators: [
      new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: 'jpeg' }),
    ],
  }),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of NestJs, this is how I was able to get file type validation for an upload. Using the File Interceptor fileFilter option and a separate file function. The fileFilter will run the code on all files that it intercepts and return a callback of true or false on if the upload should continue.

```js
@UseInterceptors(@FileInterceptor('image', {fileFilter: ImageFileFilter})),



export const ImageFileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
    const err = new UnsupportedMediaTypeException(
      'Only image files are supported',
    )
    return callback(err, false)
  }
  callback(null, true)
}
```